# add days to existing date field in Mongoose, ExpressJS, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanted to add more days to existing Date field in mongoose.
Browser and console doesn't show any errors. What is wrong here?

```
  app.put('/api/admin/:user_id', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);

    user.userexp = user.userexp + (86400000*30);

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(200);
        });
    });
});
```

I can add days from Date.now(), but it will take current time.
How to add days for Date() inside the userexp field?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to extract Date from field and adding more days using momentjs.

```
user.userexp = moment(user.userexp).add('days',30).toDate();
```

Comment: You don't need to use moment lib just for this. you can use Date.getDate()/setDate. like   user.userexp.setDate(user.userexp.getDate() + 30).  This assume user.userexp is date object